# SSRS: saving variable from a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to replicate this code from a stored procedure in a SSRS dataset?

```
exec @dtEffective = dbo.selUpdEnv 'PrevBusDt','=',@cdUser,'N'
```

What I'm trying to do is save the effective date in a variable and display the date in a textbox.

I tried creating a parameter called `dtEffective` and use it in the dataset. But it didn't save the value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new data set with the [dbo.sqlUpdEnv] as the record source. Note that @cdUser will need to be populated first since you're passing it in, so make sure that's above @dtEffective in the parameter list. In your @dtEffective parameter, set the Default Value to the result of the data set.